# How to rerender antd Table when datasource state is updated

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
const [machineDetails, setMachineDetails] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      getData();
    }, 6000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);


  async function getData() {
       const result = await get(api)
       setMachineDetails(result.data)
    }


 <Table
    showHeader
    expandIconColumnIndex={4}
    columns={columns}       
    dataSource={machineDetails}
    rowKey={(record) => record.machineID}
  />
```

for the columns am assigning the values from `machineDetails` state. here for every 6 sec state is going to change(not all the time) but when it changes the table is not updated automatically it's showing the old values, how to solve this

Comment: Since the dependency array passed to the useEffect is empty array, the effect runs only once and that is on the initial render. Have a look at this article on how to fetch and set data https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data

Comment: I don't see any overt issue in your code. Can you try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue you see that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: @Cherubim That's ok since the `useEffect` hook is only setting up an interval timer. You typically only want to start the interval when the component mounts, and clear any running interval timers when the component unmounts.

Comment: you can use `SWR`: https://swr.vercel.app/ and set it to revalidate at any interval you want

Comment: @athavan, did you solve this issue?